# how to write trace io files for disksim simulator?

Tags: trace, simulator

I want to show a performance graph for different AP ratios(parity bits/data bits) for the flash memory present in my PC. I need to give trace file input for that. Please help me on how to write a trace file .This is first time working on simulators.